# Currency column with no decimals: add in decimal

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, decimal, currency

I've been reviewing a currency column that has no decimal spaces. It's an output from a legacy system loaded into our Oracle database.

If the field has three or more numerals it should have a decimal at three spaces right.

If the value has less than three numerals, it should have a decimal and a leading zero.

For example:

- 2050 should be converted to 2.050
- 110 should be converted to .110
- 50 should be converted to .050

I've tried using cast, but I received the error 'invalid datatype.'

It's a basic select statement:

```
    select 
    customer_id
    cast(ENDING_BALANCE as (decimal(10,3)) as Bal_1
    from Current_Balances
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You have an extra parentheses just before the word decimal it seems. Try `cast(ENDING_BALANCE as decimal(10,3))`

Comment: Thanks for the catch @scsimon. This time it ran, but didn't add in the decimal.

Comment: What is the data type of the inputs? Are they NUMBER or VARCHAR2? And what is the desired data type of the result - NUMBER or VARCHAR2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to cast it to a number and divide by 1000

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('2050' as INT)/1000 as DECIMAL(10,3)) FROM DUAL
```

If you really mean to have the output format looking like that, you need to TO_CHAR it

```
SELECT LTRIM(TO_CHAR(CAST('2050' as INT)/1000, 'FM0.000'), '0') FROM DUAL
```